# Find longest common suffix in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I have a string of DNS names seperated by `,` like this:

```
b-1.cluster.abcdef.c2.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com,b-2.cluster.abcdef.c2.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com,b-3.cluster.abcdef.c2.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

I want to find the longest common suffix of these strings, which in this case is `.cluster.abcdef.c2.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

How can I achieve this in Terraform?

Comment: The example is a real one

Comment: Yes but I don't want the strings to be hard-coded.

Comment: Did you already try a regular expression?

Comment: I don't see how regex is applicable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple if you use a proper programming language:

```py
# util.py
import os.path as p
import sys
import json

r_dns_names = sys.argv[1][::-1]
r_split_dns_names = r_dns_names.split(",")

print(json.dumps({"output": p.commonprefix(r_split_dns_names)[::-1]}))
```

```
locals {
  s = "b-1.cluster.abcdef.c2.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com,b-2.cluster.abcdef.c2.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com,b-3.cluster.abcdef.c2.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
}

data "external" "util" {
  program = ["python3","util.py","${local.s}"]
}

output "dns" {
  value = data.external.util.result.output
}
```

```bash
$ terraform apply -auto-approve
...
Outputs:

dns = ".cluster.abcdef.c2.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
```

Comment: This definitely works! I would prefer a pure-HCL solution but if none appears I will mark this as the answer

Comment: @sdgfsdh I truly doubt you'll be able to do this in terraform